# how to change each buttons values in a loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i have many follow buttons and each button is linked with a specific user. now when a user clicks on the button it should change from follow to following for each button that is clicked in the div

i tried achieveing this by using this method:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.msg-action').each(function(){
   $("#follow-button2").click(function(){
    if ($("#follow-button2").text().trim() == "Follow"){
        $("#follow-button2").text('Following');

    }else{
        $("#follow-button2").text('Follow');

   }
   });
   });
 });
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
if i do this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#follow-button2").click(function(){
    if ($("#follow-button2").text().trim() == "Follow"){
        $("#follow-button2").text('Following');

    }else{
        $("#follow-button2").text('Follow');

   }
  });
  });
```

only the first instance of a button will be changed and others wont, because jquery understands the first instance of the class or id i am referring to.

my HTML CODE:

```
while($row3 = $query->fetch())
 {


  ?>
    <div Class="inside-card" 
                <td>
        <div class="msg-body">
        </a>
            </img>

                <div class="msg-action">

        <form method="POST" action='' name="followForm">

        <button  id="follow-button2" class='msg-icon' name="follow" type="submit" value="follow" onclick=""><span id="follow_id">Follow</span>  
            <input  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $follower_username; ?>" name="follow_id"/>
        </button>

 ?>
```

so is there a way to use jquery to change every clicked button?

Comment: I only see one button in your HTML code.

Comment: please check the edits, i kept the while loop out of the question for simplicity @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: Your loop produces invalid HTML, because the `id` attribute has to be unique on all elements. Instead, remove the `id` and add it as a `class`. `class="msg-icon follow-button2"` - in your jquery, select the element with `$('.follow-button2')`. Inside your onclick handler, you can use `$(this)` to change _only_ the clicked button.

Comment: IDs must be unique so `$("#follow-button2")` will only select the first element with that ID in the document. Select by class and use `$(this)` to access the clicked element within the click handler.

Comment: @Turnip i made the code this way $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".follow-button2").click(function(){
  if $((this).text().trim() == "Follow"){
   $(this).text('Following');
   
  }else{
   $(this).text('Follow');

       }
});
}); but it is giving me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `span` inside your each button

```
 <span style="display:none">Following</span>
```

Change the `id` of your button to `class` like

```
      // your while loop starts
      // add this as your button in your while loop
      <button  class="follow-button" class='msg-icon' name="follow" type="submit" value="follow" ><span id="follow_id">Follow</span>  
        <input  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $follower_username; ?>" name="follow_id"/>
        <span style="display:none">Following</span>
    </button>

     // your loop ends
```

and Add this `js`

```
$('.follow-button').click(function(){


  $(this).find('span').toggle();

});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gea9zohd/14/), tested, working 100% correct.

Comment: its working but its not showing the following, when i click its just an empty button with no text

Comment: did you added `<span style="display:none">Following</span>` to your button in your while loop html ?

Answer (score 0):

First get all follow buttons and create an array to make it easier to iterate over the collection.

```
const followButtonClass = "msg-action";
const getFollowButtonsByClass = (className) => document.getElementsByClassName(className);
const followButtons = [...getFollowButtonsByClass(followButtonClass)];
```

Then attach the event to each follow button to change text when someone clicks on it.

```
const followToggleHandler = (event) => 
   event.target.textContent === "Follow" ?
   event.target.textContent = "Following" : 
   event.target.textContent = "Follow"; // This will change to follow again when user clicks again

followButtons.forEach(x => {
    x.addEventListener("click", followToggleHandler);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you're iterating parent elements but actually calling the single child element with this:

```js
$("#follow-button2").text('Following');
```

If you want to access *every* element with `id="follow-button2"`, you have to iterate child selector and access it with `$(this)` inside. Try something like this:

```js
$("#follow-button2").each(function(index) {
    // the context changed => use $(this) to access each element
    if ($(this).text().trim() == "Follow"){
        $(this).text('Following');

    }else{
        $(this).text('Follow');
   }
});
```

Comment: this is very close but it is still not changing.